# How pass json array in Angular post method and how get this array in Api?

Tags: java, json, spring, angular, api

**My Post method in Angular**

```
     private attachAuthorization(): RequestOptions {
     const headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('HttpHeaders.ACCEPT', 'MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'charset=UTF-8');
headers.append ('Authorization',sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
//console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
const options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  responseType: ResponseContentType.Json,
});

return options;}


public post(url: string, requestData: any):any {
const options = this.attachAuthorization();
return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(requestData),options);


}
```

---

**Json Array**

[{"columnname":"symbol","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"String"},{"columnname":"order_Receiving_Date","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"DateRange"},{"columnname":"event_Type","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"String"},{"columnname":"firm_ROE_ID","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"int"},{"columnname":"rejected_ROE_ID","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"int"}]

---

**API Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Oats-Exception-summary"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>> OatsExceptionSummaryPost(
         @RequestBody JSONArray payload)throws SQLException,JSONException,Exception {
    System.out.println(payload);
    String FilterData="";
    /*JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(payload);*/
    List<OatsExceptionSummary> Data =ISurveillanceService.getOatsExecptionSummary(FilterData);  
     if (Data.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>>(Data, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
 }
```

---

**Error in API **

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing: public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   com.zcon.RSMS.SpringBoot_RSMS2.controller.SurveillanceController.OatsExceptionSummaryPost(org.json.JSONArray)
>   throws
>   java.sql.SQLException,org.json.JSONException,java.lang.Exception
>   2018-05-22 12:56:09.624  WARN 11855 --- [nio-8090-exec-4]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing: public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   com.zcon.RSMS.SpringBoot_RSMS2.controller.SurveillanceController.OatsExceptionSummaryPost(org.json.JSONArray)
>   throws
>   java.sql.SQLException,org.json.JSONException,java.lang.Exception

Comment: What do you see when you do `System.out.println(payload);`?

Comment: when I was passed through postman it printed but not work when send json array through Angular post method..so what I do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** ..The problem is I have send empty Array reauestData[ ] but now 
I have changed array to json object

{

"data":
[

{"columnname":"symbol","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"String"},{"columnname":"order_Receiving_Date","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"DateRange"},{"columnname":"event_Type","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"String"},{"columnname":"firm_ROE_ID","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"int"},{"columnname":"rejected_ROE_ID","filterby":"","values":"","time":"","datatype":"int"}

]

}

---

**Post Method**

component.ts

```
prepareData() {


console.log("this.FilterData"+JSON.stringify(this.FilterData)); 
  this.loading = true;
   this.SharedHttpClientService.post(
    this.UrlsService.setAPIURl(
      APIURL.Surveillance_OatsException_Summary),
      this.FilterData)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.isRateLimitReached = false;
      return response.json();
    })
    .subscribe(Element => {
      this.dataset=Element;
    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        this.isRateLimitReached = true;
    });
    this.loading = false;


}
```

---

service.ts

```
 private attachAuthorization(): RequestOptions {
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//headers.append('HttpHeaders.ACCEPT', 'MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE');
headers.append ('Authorization',sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
//console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));

const options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  responseType: ResponseContentType.Json,

});

return options;
  }



public post(url: string, requestData: any):Observable<any>{
const options = this.attachAuthorization();
//console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
let Data={"data":requestData}
console.log("Data "+JSON.stringify(Data)); 
return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(Data),options);                                                                                                        


 }
```

---

**API controller Function**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/Oats-Exception-summary/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>> OatsExceptionSummaryPost(
             @RequestBody Map payload)throws SQLException,JSONException,Exception {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject( payload);
        JSONArray dataArray = root.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int t=0; t<dataArray.length(); t++) {
            JSONObject JObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(t);
            System.out.println(JObject.getString("columnname"));
        }

        String FilterData="";
        //JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(payload);
        List<OatsExceptionSummary> Data =ISurveillanceService.getOatsExecptionSummary(FilterData);  
         if (Data.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<OatsExceptionSummary>>(Data, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//fist convert your json array into typescript

  //  than assin to any variable like
   documents: [{
           columnname: string;
           filterby: string;
           values: string;
           time: string;
           datatype: string;
        }];
 //than pass to in service like below
this.profileService.saveProfile(this.documents)
            .subscribe(response => { });
   //than use in your http post service like below example
 saveProfile(formData): Observable<any> {

                    return this.http.post(this.requestUrl, formData)
                      .map((res: Response) => {return res.json()})
                      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're stringifying the post body while your API expects a JSON array. Just remove the `JSON.stringify` and try again.

```
return this.http.post(url, requestData, options);
```

Comment: can you do console.log(requestData) and let me know the result

Comment: requestData [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]